# Why are there two different definitions of multiset union

Tags: multisets

I just realized that you can use two different definitions of multiset union:

First definition:

- (M⊎N)(x)=M(x)+N(x)

Second definition:

- (M⋓N)(x)=max(M(x),N(x))

I understand the difference between them but I'm not sure I understand why these two definitions exists, and in which real life use cases you would use the one over the other.

> Does anyone have an example that can explain the need of these two
>   different definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers and let $A$ and $B$ be the multiset of their prime factors. For example, if $a=60$ then $A=\{\{ 2,2,3,5\}\}$.

Then $A\uplus B$ is the prime factors of $ab$ and $A\Cup B$ is the prime factors of $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.